# jsgrid plugin > Filter not working with "POST" reqest JSON

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I have this code:

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    height: "auto",
    width: "100%",
    sorting: true,
filtering: true,
    paging: false,
    autoload: true,
    pageLoading: false,

    controller: {
        loadData: function(filter) {    

    var d = $.Deferred();
             $.ajax({
                processData: false,
                type:"POST",
                url: "http://blabla/api/database/sp",
                data: JSON.stringify(storedproceduredata),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(response) {
                if (filter) {
                    if (filter.field1 && filter.field1 != "")
                        response.results = response.results.filter(r => r.field1 === filter.field1);
                    if (filter.ID_field2 && filter.ID_field2 != "")
                        response.results = response.results.filter(r => r.field2 === filter.ID_field2);
                    if (filter.field2 && filter.field3 != "")
                        response.results = response.results.filter(r => r.field3 === filter.field3);
                }                   d.resolve(response.results);
            });

            return d.promise();
        }
    },

    fields: [
        { name: "field1", type: "text" },
        { name: "field2", type: "text", width: 150 },
    { name: "field3", type: "text", width: 150 }
    ]
});
});
```

I tried to get filter working with the $.grep example but it is not working. What can be problem here?

The filter object is filled with my filter field. But in some examples the data parameter is also "filter". Which is not possible in my case As I need it to get my data.

The Response object is like this:

```
Response
  results
     1
        Field1     value
        Field2     another value 
     2
        Field1      value
        Field2      another value

 etc.....
```

Comment: We have no idea what the value of `response.results` is, so it is really hard to tell why your code "is not working"

Comment: Sorry ;-) edited my original post

Comment: Can someone help me out please?
I do not understand the approach as well. I just retrieve the data once and than try to apply the filter which get loaded in the grid. How can it work that way?

Comment: I changed my code. Now I get results in my grid. However, filtering is still not working.

Comment: I now know my problem is not that much related by the way the filter is populated but because of the trip to the server again. I will close this issue and create a new one.